# Create Pdf from a database using a query like 'Select * from some_table where some condition'

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, itext

I have a requirement where i have to create pdf from database. There are almost 12 such requirement.

All them have the same aim though. That is to show the `ResultSet` returned from my `pstmt.executeQuery()`into some kind of table.

All i know right now is that i will have to use iText jars to accomplish this. Can someone can guide me how to go about doing this ?

I want to make something like this

```
public static void createPdf(String query){
    //Code to create Pdf Table
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidate the `ResultSet` entries into a `List<Object[]>`

A table in the PDF will have as many columns as one of the entries in the list. For eg;-

```
int numberOfColumns = results.get(0).length;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(numberOfColumns);
```

Iterate over the results list, and over the `Object[]`. Keep adding the values to the table:

```
//obj is an entry in the `Object[]`
 table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(obj)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book) or browse the examples, you'll find dozens of examples that do exactly what you want. For instance: the [HeaderFooter1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=86) example takes a `ResultSet` from a movie database and creates a [PDF showing different tables listing movie screenings per day](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter04/header_footer_1.pdf). In case you wonder why several people voted to close your question: it is assumed that you read documentation before you post a question.